# Play framework xss via flash success/error messages

Tags: playframework, xss, playframework-1.x

In play framework Flash cookie is not signed, making it possible for the user to modify it. When i use it to pass error message from one request to another and print it like this in my template

```
&{flash.error}
```

error message may contain an evil html injection code. 
This is exactly how framework tutorials tell me to do, so is it really a security hole or i am just paranoid?

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you are getting the flash value from.  If you are generating it from a string in your script that you set then that is fine, but where you will run into security issues is when you use that mechanism to postback user input.